# jQuery and Repeat Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I create animation for move element into div , the div animate ok , the problem it´s when i try repit this animation using setInterval

**I put my code here :**

```
$("#header").fadeIn(100, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'left': '-1600'
    }, 8000);
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#header").fadeIn(100, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'left': '-1600'
        }, 8000);
    });
}, 10000);
```

The first works fine but the second no works ok , if i change position - animate function - show but no repit , i supose with setInterval repit other time but no works me , howewer i need use other function and no setInterval  .....

Regards

Comment: Because you move it to -1600 everytime. Not -3200, -4800, -6400 etc etc..

Comment: The scrit animate image and need move to this position , and repit the same animation start from 600 and move to -1600

Comment: Ah, then it's probably because it never returns to the starting point at 600 :)

Comment: Ok and how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because it never returns to the starting point. Here's an example of a repeating animation. I do not have your html or css, so I made up my own. In the demo it goes to 500, so it doesn't go outside the screen.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/haEJb/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").fadeIn(100, function() {
        console.log('go!');
        $(this).animate({
            'left': '-1600'
        }, 8000);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#header").css('left','0').fadeIn(100, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'left': '-1600'
            }, 8000);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Ah ok i need return animation the first point and repit ok , perfect , thank´s !